# Parsing boolean from configuration section in web.config

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a custom configuration section in my web.config.

One of my classes is grabbing from this:

```
<myConfigSection LabelVisible="" TitleVisible="true"/>
```

I have things working for parsing if I have true or false, however if the attribute is blank I am getting errors. When the config section tries to map the class to the configuration section I get an error of "not a valid value for bool" on the 'LabelVisible' part.

How can I parse "" as false in my myConfigSection class?

I have tried this:

```
    [ConfigurationProperty("labelsVisible", DefaultValue = true, IsRequired = false)]
    public bool? LabelsVisible
    {
        get
        {

            return (bool?)this["labelsVisible"];

        }
```

But when I try and use what is returned like so:

```
graph.Label.Visible = myConfigSection.LabelsVisible;
```

I get an error of:

```
'Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that `graph.Label.Visible` is of type `bool` but `myConfigSection.LabelsVisible` is of type `bool?`. There is no implicit conversion from `bool?` to `bool` because this a narrowing conversion. There are several ways to solve this:

1: Cast `myConfigSection.LabelsVisible` to a `bool`:

```
graph.Label.Visible = (bool)myConfigSection.LabelsVisible;
```

2: Extract the underlying `bool` value from `myConfigSection.LabelsVisible`:

```
graph.Label.Visible = myConfigSection.LabelsVisible.Value;
```

3: Add logic to capture when `myConfigSection.LabelsVisible` represents the `null` value:

```
graph.Label.Visible = myConfigSection.LabelsVisible.HasValue ?
                          myConfigSection.LabelsVisible.Value : true;
```

4: Interalize this logic to `myConfigSection.LabelsVisible`:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("labelsVisible", DefaultValue = true, IsRequired = false)]
public bool LabelsVisible {
    get {
        bool? b= (bool?)this["labelsVisible"];
        return b.HasValue ? b.Value : true;
    }
}
```

It is one of the latter two approaches that is best to avoid some exceptions that would occur if you use the other solutions when `myConfigSection.LabelsVisible` represents the `null` value. And the best solution is to internalize this logic into the `myConfigSection.LabelsVisible` property getter.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This is extremely helpful. What specifically is the '?' on the end of 'bool?' called? NullableType?

Comment: The syntax `T?` where `T` is a value type is a short way of saying `Nullable<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little dangerous, but technically works: (you'll get an InvalidOperationException if the value of the nullable is indeed null):

```
graph.Label.Visible = (bool)myConfigSection.LabelsVisible;
```

You should verify the nullable to see if it's been set:

```
bool defaultValue = true;
graph.Label.Visible = myConfigSection.LabelsVisible ?? defaultValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
graph.Label.Visible = myConfigSection.LabelsVisible.HasValue ? myConfigSection.LabelsVisible.Value : false;
```

Comment: Other version is:

graph.Label.Visible = myConfigSection.LabelsVisible.Value ?? false;

Comment: @jaloplo: No. `myConfigSection.LabelsVisible.Value` is of type `bool` but the `??` operator is reserved for left-hand operands of reference type.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (myConfigSection.LabelsVisible.HasValue)
{
    graph.Label.Visible = myConfigSection.LabelsVisible.Value;
}
```

Comment: And what if `myConfigSection.LabelsVisible.HasValue` is `false`?

Comment: Then `graph.Label.Visible` won't change its value. The OP didn't specify the desired behavior in case `LabelVisible=""` in his config file.